# How can I create messenger Textbox in blackberry application

Tags: blackberry

I would like to create textbox that support text message and image(emoticon) like bb messenger textbox.

Could anyone help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to be looking at the `net.rim.blackberry.api.mail` API.

Some notable areas are `BodyPart.ContentType` and `Part`.

A link to the API documentation: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/blackberry/api/mail/package-summary.html

Comment: You can put a Part into an EditField?

Comment: How to implements that with EditField?